# Resample in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

I want to resample at minute but the value of the sample at minute t must come from the last previous value.

However, doing a resample.last(), it takes the last value of the current set.

How to do ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is always better to accompany your post here with examples of the data and desired output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `last`, for previous values add [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = df.resample('1Min').last().shift()
```

Comment: read about the shift() function, but I didn't understand how it works, does it shift directly on the previous value?

Comment: @Lidse - exactly, `last` create consecutive DatetimeIndex and shift is for shifting by one row.